# Rails create object params null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-gem

After create a product and using wicked gem to update the object the log is spiting

on the redirect to step that params becomes null. someone have any idea why?

```
[object Object]

HTTP_REFERER    http://localhost:3000/products/new?
params  null
utf8    ✓


def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
    if @product.save

      redirect_to product_step_path(@product, Product.form_steps.first, only_path: true, format: :html)

    else
      render :new, format: :html
    end
  end

class Product::StepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps *Product.form_steps

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

    render_wizard 
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> on the redirect to step that params becomes null. someone have any idea why?

Yes. Because you told it to do so.

```
  redirect_to product_step_path(@product, Product.form_steps.first, only_path: true, format: :html)
```

You are going to a new page with new parameters. If you want to some parameters of the current request to be available in this next requests, specify them in the `redirect_to`.

Comment: thank you @SergioTulentsev but the

redirect_to product_step_path(@product, Product.form_steps.first, only_path: true, format: :html)

is not already  specified?

i how i specify?

Comment: @japalow: something like this: `redirect_to product_step_path(@product, Product.form_steps.first, only_path: true, format: :html, foobar: params[:foobar])`